# How do I sell ETZ?

Tags: myetherwallet

I have some ETH in myetherwallet and realize that I now also have an equal amount of ETZ? How/where should I send this to in order to cash it in? In fact, how do I even view it?

Comment: i cannt make deposit in yobit.net i take got this massage " Deposit for such currency is temporary off " how can i do ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19515)

Comment: I have same problem. I'm mining etz and i dont know where to sell it

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19703)

Answer (score 1):

You can sell etz on etherdelta

and here https://exrates.me

Answer (score 0):

ETZ is currently listed on Yobit. You can transfer  your ETZ to Yobit and trade for  ETH, BTC or Doge.

Comment: Actually, you can't at the moment (2018-01-26). The exchange says that the wallet is temporarily off.

Answer (score 0):

You can trade ETZ to ETH at https://www.hqex.io .  I find the interface as very convenient.